# Eliminating duplicate data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a new user in VBA and I wrote the following basic code in order to eliminate duplicate data in one sheet and extract unique data into another sheet.

For example:

1. in *Sheet1* there are total number of 184 cells which contains the same date (12/07/2007) in Column A.
2. I desire to take **one** of that date data and write it to a cell in *Sheet2*.
3. Therefore, there will be 12/07/2007 written in A1 in Sheet2.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Code:

```
Sub Take_Unique()

    Workbooks("historicaldata.xls").Activate
    Dim i As String
    Dim xrow As Long
    xrow = 2
    Do Until Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 1) = ""
        If Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(xrow + 1, 1) Then
           Sheet12.Cells(xrow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 1)
        End If
        xrow = xrow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code as written?

Comment: It just eliminates one of the date data and 183 of them still remains.

Comment: Why not just use either the `Remove Duplicates` feature or the `Advanced Filter`?

Comment: Thanks! However, it is going to be a part of a longer code. So, VBA usage is necessary for me.

Comment: Either of those can be incorporated into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler to just copy the whole column from sheet1 to sheet12:

```
Sheet1.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheet12.Columns(1)
```

Then use the `RemoveDuplicates` functionality to drop any duplicates (set the Header if it's present and not if it isn't)

```
Sheet12.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dave! Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is my [duplicate master addin](https://stackexchange.com/users/321941/brettdj).

It handles whitespace, case sensitivities and even regexp matches - so it goes beyond the default comparison.